# How to Rename a Unity Project?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I want to change the name of a Unity project to something else such that Unity Editor shows the new name at the top or when I open a script using Visual Studio, it shows the new name at the top of VS. How to do that?

Does changing the project name change the game's name (the name that appears on top left corner of the game window)?

Does changing project name change the name of the game's executable file?

Answer (score 120, accepted):

To change **Unity project name**:

1. **Change the unity project folder name (the parent folder of 'Assets'
   folder)**
2. **Remove any file with .sln or .csproj suffixes under the project
       folder.** (Unity will regenerate them)

> Does changing the project name change the game's name (the name that
>   appears on top left corner of the game window)?

No! To **change the game's name** go to **Edit > Project Settings > Player > Product Name** and change it to the new name.

> Does changing project name change the name of the game's executable
>   file?

No! when it comes to create a build for your game (by **File > Build Settings**), Unity asks you about the file name. That name becomes the name of your executable file (on PC).

> How do I open the project after doing all this?

In the top right of the Unity launcher, click 'Open'.  Find and select the project folder (i.e. parent folder of the 'Assets' folder) and click 'Select Folder'. The project opens in the Unity Editor.

> Does this technique work in Unity v5.6.3?

Yes!

> Does this technique work in Unity v2017.2.0b6 ?

Partially!  Step1 (Renaming the project folder name & deleting the .csproj & .sln files) still works, 
However Step2 (**Edit > Project Settings > Player > Product Name**) does not retain changes to Product Name or Company name for some reason (most likely a bug)

Step 2 (Change Game Name) Workaround:

-Close Unity.
-Directly edit those field values inside the ProjectSettings\ProjectSettings.asset file with your favourite text editor.

-Open Unity, confirm field has changed in **Edit > Project Settings > Player > Product Name**

Comment: I want the entire unity project to be in a subfolder of the 'main' project folder, which will contain things like docs and source control hidden folders, build artifact folders, etc. I'd like to name the Unity project folder "source". Is there any way to do this without unity also renaming the .sln to "source.sln"?

Comment: You could also add in removal of the .vs (hidden?) folder.

Comment: I ran into an issue with changing the name of a project referenced in a cloud project.  I also set cloudEnabled to 0, cloudProjectId to 0, and deleted the lines under cloudServicesEnabled (including that line) in the project assets file.  When opening the project, it allowed me to enable re-upload everything to the cloud under the new name.

Answer (score 1):

take notice that there is a "product name" and a "project name". Either way, changing project name and product name did not change the name displayed in the services window (or project dashboard in unity id webpage)

Answer (score 0):

Changing the 'project name' and 'product name' is great for *local* projects.

If your project is in any way using Unity services (cloud things), then rename the project via its Unity (web-based) dashboard.
Quickest way is using the three dots inside the Unity launcher, next to every cloud-services-enabled project.

This way, Unity will take care of renaming the project across its services, not just your local folder.

Answer (score 0):

For windows 11 If you're using the unity hub you right click on a project and hit  show in explorer you find the file with your project name and you right click on that you click on show more options And then at the bottom it should say rename This varies depending on your version of Windows as of the different File Explorer architectures

Comment: This is just renaming the folder the project is in, which is the same as the accepted answer